# What is the meaning of col in colVariable name?

Tags: vba, outlook

I’m learning VBA for Outlook and have seen some examples like the one below defining variables. I guess the o in the beginning of some variables mean object, right? But what is the meaning of col ? Maybe ol stands for outlook, but then what about the c ? I don’t believe col is for columns, but maybe I’m wrong.

```
Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules 

 Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule 

 Dim colRuleActions As Outlook.RuleActions 

 Dim oMoveRuleAction As Outlook.MoveOrCopyRuleAction 

 Dim oFromCondition As Outlook.ToOrFromRuleCondition 

 Dim oExceptSubject As Outlook.TextRuleCondition 

 Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder 

 Dim oMoveTarget As Outlook.Folder
```

Comment: Variable names are arbitrary. You'd have to ask the person that wrote the code what they mean.

Comment: Well, it is code written by Microsoft, so I thought it was some (Microsoft) standard way of naming variables.

Comment: `col` probably indicates "collection" - a set of one or more items.  `o` is either "outlook" or "object"

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams, it most certainly stands for collection. It is some time hard to understand for us not having English as first language.

Comment: The question wasn't stupid. But because this is about a variable name and programmers decide variable names its very possible this question has no answer. Although you got a satisfactory answer there really is no way of knowing what 'col' actually refers to outside of asking the programmer. These opinion based type of questions should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables in the code you provided are written in what is known as [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). In short, hungarian notation uses a common set of letters to designate the variable type at the beginning of the variable name.

```
l = long type
s = string type
col = collection ...
```

The code in your original question refers to the collection of outlook rules in

```
Dim colRules as Outlook.Rules
```

and the rule object in

```
Dim oRule as Outlook.Rule
```

For a bit more nuance, the code in your original question declares all variables in one spot and then presumably uses them later. My preferred way of programming, for maintainability and readability, is to declare all variables at the moment they will be used and use Pascal (or Camel Case) and give them meaningful names.

For example

```
Dim theOutlook as Outlook.Application
Set theOutlook = new Outlook.Application
```

Or

```
Dim rowCount as Long
rowCount = Range("A1:A100").Rows.Count 'using Excel
```